# In C,To Store more values in database(files) type int and call the specific line

Tags: c, arrays, database, file, arraylist

In C, how to store array in file(database) and how to access it in program. In this program when I enter index number for ex.2 (which contains 30), after I want to subtract the age by 5 then it shows 25 but when I want to change the index number 2 then it subtracted from 25,,,not from the given index
For example
I have store value in database(data2.txt) file
Like this..
10
20
30
40
And I want to excess or update the value(30) so what can change I can do...

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #define PATH "/storage/emulated/0/c language/data2.txt"
    int main()
    {
        FILE *file;
        int age[], s, i;
        printf("Enter the array index:");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        file = fopen(PATH, "r");
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("files does not exist");
            return 1;
        }
        fscanf(file, "%d", &age[i]);
        fclose(file);
        printf("Enter how much age should to be subtracted:");
        scanf("%d", &s);
        file = fopen(PATH, "w");
        age[i] = age[i] - s;
        fprintf(file, "%d", age[i]);
        fclose(file);
        printf("%d", age[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to reset your file you should use "a" parametr because now when u want to update value in file you are saving only 25(like in ex) all other values are gone (But "a" appends saved value on EOF). If I get this correct you are trying to read 3 variable from file, but when u are doing it:

```
fscanf(file, "%d", &age[i]);
```

you are getting only first variable in file. If you want to get third one you need to call out this function 2 more times.

Its better to get all data into array in loop and then operate on array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 40
    int main()
    {
        FILE *file;
        int age[SIZE], s,i, j=0;
        printf("Enter the array index:");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("files does not exist");
            return 1;
        }
        while(1){ //getting all data from file to array
          if(feof(file))
            break;
          fscanf(file, "%d", &age[j++]); 
        }
        for(int x=0;x<j;x++)
          printf("%d ",age[x]);
        fclose(file);
        printf("\nEnter how much age should to be subtracted:");
        scanf("%d", &s);
        file = fopen("data.txt", "w");
        age[i] -= s;
        for(int k=0;k<j;k++) //passing updated data to file
          fprintf(file, "%d ", age[k]);
        fclose(file);
    }
```

Comment: When u are using file = fopen(PATH, "w"); your previous data form file is gone.
New data will be written in its spot, when you are using fscanf(file, "%d", &age[i]); you are getting only first data from file, and also when u define your age array you  should define size of it.

Comment: How ro store more value in database

Comment: And I want to display the specific line in database to c program..

Comment: Like.       10.   20 30 40 in database I want to excess only 30 how you plz write the program

Comment: I wrote edit tell me if u wanted it to work like that

Comment: In your edit program there is big error I don't understand that (intial there are 3 value) after excess the increase of garbage value take place...